# jquery DOM function returns undefined but javascript version works

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Here is the current function in javascript which works:

```
var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
var originPrice = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName('price type2')[0].innerHTML;
```

And this is the jquery version which I'm still learning, and which doesn't work

```
var originPrice = $('iframe').contents().find('.price type2')[0].html();
```

The error returned by firefox is that the it's "Undefined". What could be the error here?

Thanks for any tips, I'm still learning jquery

Comment: I think you need `.find('.price.type2')` (note the extra `.`) but I'm not sure on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `[0]` on a jQuery object, you get back a DOM object which does not have a `.html()` method because that's a jQuery method.

Either use `.eq(0).html()` to get a jQuery object or use `[0].innerHTML` if you have a DOM object.

Also, change your selector to `find('.price.type2')` to look for a single object with two classes "price" and "type2"
.

Comment: I need to return the value inside which is a number. The .eq(0).html() method returns null for me. But the [0].innerHTML gets error "Undefined". How do I return the value inside with the eq(0).html() method? Thanks

Comment: @jc.yin most likely your selector doesn't find anything

Comment: @jc.yin try using `.find('.price.type2')` instead of `.find('.price type2')`

Comment: Yep, `.eq(0).html()` and `.find('.price.type2')` works for this. Thanks Jan!

Comment: btw, I just want to know, whats the difference between .price.type2 and .price type2? Why is there the extra dot?

Comment: In a selector, if you want to look for a class name, it must be preceded by a dot.  If there is no character at the beginning of the word, then it looks for a tag of that name.  If you want the same object to have two classes, you do not put a space between them like `".price.type2"`.

Answer (score 1):

Because when you selected `[0]`, you returned a DOM element instead of a jQuery object. And DOM elements don't have the `html()` function.

```
var originPrice = $('iframe').contents().find('.price.type2').eq(0).html();
```

Comment: most likely `.find('.price.type2')` is correct, not `.find('.price type2')`